# AngularJS UI-Bootstrap Modal prompt on escape

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

In UI-Bootstrap modal how to prompt a user with a message "Are you sure ...." when the user presses escape key?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to set up a directive that listens for that event

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']).directive('confirmExit', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
      elm.bind('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 27){ //27 represents escape 
          //modal code in here
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Now you attach this to the body tag

```
<body confirm-exit>
```

You can add an alert in the "modal code in here" comment to check if the directive is working.  keyCode === 27 is for exit

Make sure if you're using modals that you inject the modal into the directive

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LofNlt?p=preview) for it